Is there a way to prevent ROW_NUMBER's ORDER BY from having to repeat the same thing?
I currently have this SQL:
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by priority DESC NULLS LAST,
                                   created_at DESC) as index
     , id
     , title
     , ago(created_at)
     , priority
     , user_id 
from post 
order by priority DESC NULLS LAST
       , created_at DESC;

As you can see, I need to have ROW_NUMBER() and that needs the
(order by priority desc nulls last, created_at desc) as index, 
id, title, ago(created_at)

This is causing me to repeat the same long
order by priority desc nulls last, created_at desc

twice.
If I need to have even more columns in the order by, that will make it even longer.
Is there a way to prevent this repetition? I tried using an alias after the ORDER BY but that doesn't seem to be supported.

You can also use the row_number()'s alias in your outer query sorting, order by index. @Frank Heikens' column ordinal number syntax is even shorter. If you're looking to re-use the window definition, you can define it separately using window w1 as (order by..), then row_number over () becomes row_number over w1

Just order by the first column:
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY priority DESC NULLS LAST, created_at DESC) AS index
     , id
     , title
     , ago(created_at)
     , priority
     , user_id
FROM post
ORDER BY 1 ASC; -- 1 = first column

See also the manual

SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY priority DESC NULLS LAST, created_at DESC) as index,
  id,
  title,
  ago(created_at),
  priority,
  user_id
FROM post
ORDER BY index;


This makes the query even longer than just repeating the column names and direction. Besides that, there is no need for a subquery.
